# Android SDK installation errors

Tags: android

Installing the Android SDK. Got Eclipse Juno (latest version). Ran into some minor issues with the installation, but managed to get past them. But now I have one I just can't work through. I've downloaded the Eclipse ADT Plugin. When I restart Eclipse, it gives me this error: "This version of ADT requires Android SDK Tools in revision 20.0.0 or above. Current revision is 16.0.0. Please update your SDK Tools to the latest version." The error dialog box gives me a button to open the SDK Manager, which I take. It opens the SDK Manager and it finds the new packages that I need. When I go to install them, I get ANOTHER error. The log says:

```
"Failed to rename directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools to 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\PlatformToolPackage.old01."
```

and a dialog pops up telling me that it can't rename the folder and what to try to get it to work. It never works, and I have to Cancel everything all the way back to Eclipse (which is still miffed that I don't have the latest stuff).

I've tried rebooting and such, but it doesn't help. I tried running the SDK Manager as Admin, but when I do that, it thinks it has all the latest stuff (weird) and won't want to download anything.

Just FYI, I have Rev. 16 of the Android SDK Tools (it wants 20) and have Rev. 10 of the Android SDK Platform-tools (it wants 12).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: fwiw, I wouldn't recommend putting the SDK in Program Files just because there are a lot of things in the SDK and the NDK that don't jive too well with spaces in the path - may or may not be the source of your current troubles.  Ideally, you'd install linux somewhere and work that way (trust me, it's worth it for android dev)

Answer (score 0):

Did you start eclipse as an Administrator? If not, try it, sometimes eclipse just installing updates if you are an admin. 
If I update SDK, I first start SDK-Manager without eclipse to install updates. After this is done, I am doing the same in eclipse. Always do this as an admin.